# Back-up Feature Services with a script

Tags: arcgis-online, file-geodatabase, feature-service, arcgis-python-api, data-backup

**Goal:** I want to create copies of feature services and save them in a FGDB in a network folder on my machine. The overall purpose of the script is to have back-ups of my authoritative feature services from AGOL.

**What I've tried:** I originally found [How To: Download feature service items from ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS API for Python](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018909), which has the same idea (it runs without error but produces no results). The following code I've been putting together creates the FGDBs in a directory. If I understand correctly, `arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management()` will create an empty FGDB. Everything up to this point works the way I want it to. However, I'm confused as to how to get the feature services to be copied to the empty FGDBs. From here how can I use [`arcpy.management.CopyFeatures()`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/copy-features.htm) to copy the feature services to the FGDBs?

```py
from arcgis.gis import GIS
import shutil
from pathlib import Path
import os

gis = GIS("agol/url", "username", "password", verify_cert=False)
#iterate over all feature layer items and get the authoritative ones I've created
auth_items = [i for i in gis.content.search(query="owner:" + gis.users.me.username, item_type='Feature Layer', 
             max_items=-1) if i.content_status == 'org_authoritative' or i.content_status == 'public_authoritative']
rootDir = r'path\to\BackUpFiles\FeatureLayers'

#remove old directory
try:
    shutil.rmtree(rootDir)
except FileExistsError as e:
    print(e)
#create new directory
Path(rootDir).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

#create FGDBs from feature services
for a in auth_items:
    if a.type == 'Feature Service':
        name = a.title
        t = a.type
        print(f'{name} | {t}')
        arcpy.CreateFileGDB_management(rootDir, name)
```

To show you that the FGDBs are in fact created, here is a screenshot of them in Pro followed by a screenshot of where they reside in the directory. I'm also confused as to why you see files in the directory, while the FGDB in Pro is empty.

[image]

[image]

Comment: CreateFileGDB_management` only creates the container, not the feature classes ***in*** the container. An empty geodatabase contains files (the seven hidden "tables" of the geodatabase are implemented in the geodatabase). `

Comment: Thanks, I was sort of assuming that. More to the point, I'm looking for a way to write feature services to those FGDBs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the linked help doc: [How To: Download feature service items from ArcGIS Online using ArcGIS API for Python](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000018909)

- **At the time of writing** it wasn't working for me. As such, if you have multiple items of the same type they will be overwritten:
  `result = item.export('sample {}'.format(item.type), downloadFormat)`
- **Changed to:** `result = item.export(f'{item.title}', downloadFormat)`
- The "Note:" at the bottom of the page is misleading. It tells you to use `FGDB` for the parameter here: `downloadUserItems('owner', downloadFormat='FGDB')`
- **Changed to:** `downloadUserItems('owner', downloadFormat='File Geodatabase')`
- This searches the item by owner and format: `items = gis.content.search('owner:{0}'.format(owner))`
- **Changed to:** `auth_items = [i for i in gis.content.search(query="owner:" + gis.users.me.username, item_type='Feature Layer', max_items=-1) if i.content_status == 'org_authoritative' or i.content_status == 'public_authoritative']` because I'm only interested in the 'authoritative' items.

The following backs up all feature services in your AGOL content marked as 'Authoritative' . It will export them from AGOL to FGDBs and save them to whatever directory you tell it to.

```py
import arcgis
from arcgis.gis import GIS

#enter AGOL sign-in credentials
gis = GIS(None, "username", "password", verify_cert=False)


def downloadUserItems(owner, downloadFormat):
    try:
        # Search 'authoritative' items
        auth_items = [i for i in gis.content.search(query="owner:" + gis.users.me.username, item_type='Feature Layer', 
                     max_items=-1) if i.content_status == 'org_authoritative' or i.content_status == 'public_authoritative']
        # Loop through each item and if equal to Feature service then download it
        for item in auth_items:
            if item.type == 'Feature Service':
                print(item)
                result = item.export(f'{item.title}', downloadFormat)
                #r'file path of where to store the download'
                result.download(r'path\to\BackUpFiles\FeatureLayers')
                # Delete the item after it downloads to save on space
                result.delete()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
# Function takes two parameters. Username and the type of download format
# replace 'owner' with your username. replace download format with relevant format.
downloadUserItems('owner', downloadFormat='File Geodatabase')
```